# How to deal with m2m relationship(posts and tags) by doctrine(in symfony)?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

**posts** and **tags** have a **many-to-many** relationship(pretty much like stackoverflow),so the code to do it without an ORM should be:

```
$dml = "insert into posts(title,body,created) value($title,'{$_POST['post-text']}',now())";
mysql_query($dml,$con);
$pid = mysql_insert_id($con);
//deal with tags

if(isset($_POST['tagnames']))
{
 $tags = preg_split('/\s+/',trim($_POST['tagnames']));
 $list = "('".implode("',1),('", $tags)."',1)";
 $dml = "insert into tags(name,count) values $list on duplicate key update count=count+1";
 mysql_query($dml,$con);
 $list = "('" . implode("','", $tags) . "')";
 $dml = "insert into post_tags(pid,tagId) select $pid,id from tags where name in $list";
 mysql_query($dml,$con);
}
```

How to do it with by doctrine?

Suppose that the related classes are already generated from schemas

The difficulty lies in the `on duplicate key update` part.

To step further,it can be more difficult to handle when someone is editing the `posts`...

Comment: Have you considered that it might not be possible with Doctrine? You've asked this question several times and it occurs that instead of aiming for the purity of the SQL you could make the code just actually *work*. There's a simple solution that requires a few more queries, but maybe that's the tradeoff of using an ORM.

Comment: I guess it should be possible,as @Steve pointed out.Can you elaborate the solution you mentioned?Also,I think this is so frequent a usecase that ORM should have no reason to miss,But the related information is really not so much...

Comment: Why not just SELECT the existing tags (`'SELECT tags.* WHERE tags.name IN ('.implode(",", $tags).');'`) and compare the submitted tag string with each iteratively, and update/insert accordingly?

Comment: Because that's not the style symfony(or maybe ORM) deals with user submitted data.See my second comment @Steve.From the aspect of OOP,`insert/update` of `tags` obviously should be dealed in the `save` methods of `tags` model.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of managing this relationship yourself you might want to consider using [sfDoctrineActAsTaggablePlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoctrineActAsTaggablePlugin), which will probably make your life easier.

Comment: Thanks!But can you briefly describe the principle to deal with such things?As I have to deal with several other similar issues...

Comment: I've spent some time reading the code,it uses `$post->addTag('toto');` to handle `tags`,which doesn't take the benefit of sfForm,which uses the `bind` API to automate lots of stuff,so that we only need to modify the related `model` classes.Conclusion,**behaviors are not the proper tool for user submitted data**.It's more applicable for automatically generated stuff like TimeStampable,Versionable

Answer (score 0):

Well, for me it looks pretty easy.

```
$post = new Post();
$tags = Doctrine_Query::create()->from('Tags t')->whereIn('t.name', $_POST['tags'])->execute();
foreach ($tags as $tag) $post->link($tag->get('id'));
$post->save();
```

Why not [read manual](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/en/working-with-models:many-to-many-relations) first? Also please consider to generate a module with `symfony doctrine:generate-module post Post` and carefully read generated code.

Comment: Seems you don't understand the usecase I described?In your code there is no logic of inserting new `tags` into database,where the `tags` table has a **unique index** on the column `name`,and also need to update the `count` column which denotes the number of times it's used.It's the **form** processing part of symfony,but the tutos haven't covered such complex usecase so far(I've read through many online resources although..).

Comment: Hey, I know these nuances. I just thought you want to handle them by hands, not using someone's plugin.

Comment: Yes,you are right,I want to handle them by hands,as there are several other similar cases,which has no related plugins ready cooked.