# ORMers,how are you going to deal with this in the ORM style?

Tags: orm, relationship

We are modifying our post on stackoverflow.

And we only changed the **tags** part,removed `tag1`,`tag2` and added `tag3`,`tag4`.

After pressing the *Post Your Question* button,these things should be done:

1. reduced the `count` column for `tag1`,`tag2` by 1
2. delete the relation between the post and `tag1`,`tag2`
3. if `tag3`,`tag4` already exists,increase the `count` column of the two by 1;otherwise,insert them to the `tags` table with `count` value 1
4. add the relation between the post and `tag3`,`tag4`

Let's take a deep breath and that's all!

I want to see which ORM can approach this most easily/performant no matter it's written in PHP/Java/C/.Net or any language else,because the ideas are similar across languages!

Comment: What exactly we want to compare? Business model declaration? Real-life looking business methods or manually assigned properties and calling Persist() method?

Answer (score 0):

In [DataObjects.Net](http://dataobjects.net/) it will look like this. There is now any mapping files because database schema is automatically generated by ORM, including auxiliary table for question-tag relation.

Tag class:

```
[HierachyRoot]
public class Tag : Entity
{
  [Field, Key]
  public int Id { get; private set; }

  [Field(Length = 100, Indexed = true)]
  public string Name { get; private set; }

  [Field]
  public int QuestionsCount { get; set; }

  public Tag(string name) 
  {
    Name = name;
  }
}
```

Question class:

```
[HierachyRoot]
public class Question : Entity
{
  [Field, Key]
  public int Id { get; private set; }

  [Field]
  public EntitySet<Tag> Tags { get; private set; }

  // Business methods (can be placed in separate service class)

  public void AddTag(string name)
  {
    var tag = Query.All<Tag>().SingleOrDefault(t => t.Name == name);
    if (tag==null)
      tag = new Tag(name) { QuestionsCount = 1 }
    else
      tag.QuestionsCount++;
    Tags.Add(tag);
  }

  public void RemoveTag(string name)
  {
    var tag = Query.All<Tag>.Single(t => t.Name == name);
    tag.QuestionsCount--;
    Tags.Remove(tag);
  }
}
```

Application code:

```
using (Session.Open())
using (var transactionScope = Transaction.Open())
{
  var question = Query.Single<Question>(questionId);

  question.RemoveTag("tag1");
  question.RemoveTag("tag2");

  question.AddTag("tag3");
  question.AddTag("tag4");

  transactionScope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: So it'll use lots more queries than pure(non-ORM) procedural programming?

Comment: See this post for what I mean by non-ORM solution,it only requires two queries for however many tags:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392827/how-to-deal-with-m2m-relationshipposts-and-tags-by-doctrinein-symfony